# local variable 'temp' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am trying to call the below function in python. Whenever I call the following function

```
TFIDF_score = compute_TFIDF(TF_score, IDF_score)
```

I get an error `[ local variable 'temp' referenced before assignment ]`

Below is the code for reference

```
def compute_TFIDF(TF_score,IDF_score):
    TFIDF_score=[]
    for j in IDF_score:
        for i in TF_score:
            if j['key'] == i['key'] and j['doc_id'] == i['doc_id']:
                temp= {'doc_id': j['doc_id'],
                       'TFIDF_score': j['IDF_score']*i['TF_score'],
                       'key': i['key']}    
            TFIDF_score.append(temp)

    return TFIDF_score
```

Any solution as I have already assigned the temp variable and then I am passing it.

Comment: The error message said everything you need. Double check if the assign really executed before you access append. Or maybe you have wrong indent with the append statement.

Comment: It means the `temp = ...` line was *not* executed (because it's inside an `if` which apparently didn't fulfil the condition), yet you try to `append(temp)` nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

If the test in in the `if` clause is false for the first iteration, then `temp` is not defined, but you nonetheless try to unconditionnaly append it to `TDIF_score`. Also, if the test is true for the first iteration (in which case you don't have a NameError), if it evals to false on a next iteration, you'll be appending the `temp` from the previous iteration again.

Obviously you want to indent the `TFIDF_score.append(temp)` line so that it's within the `if` block:

```
for j in IDF_score:
    for i in TF_score:
        if j['key'] == i['key'] and j['doc_id'] == i['doc_id']:
            temp= {'doc_id': j['doc_id'],
                   'TFIDF_score': j['IDF_score']*i['TF_score'],
                   'key': i['key']}    
            TFIDF_score.append(temp)
```

Comment: I am trying to change the indentation but it is not working. Any alternate solution ??

Comment: "is not working" is the most useless description of a problem. And no there is no alternative solution - in Python indentation is part of the language. Chances are you have a mix of tabs and spaces for indentation, you can check this with tabnanny (https://pymotw.com/2/tabnanny/) - and make sure your editor is properly configured to use only spaces (four of them is the standard) for indentation.